Brightgauge agent cannot connect to Azure Sql Managed Instance - TLS Handshake failed
For our Brightgauge agent (third party plugin) that is installed on a local VM, it is getting the following error when we try to configure it to connect to Azure Sql Managed Instance:
TLS Handshake failed: cannot read handshake packet: EOF
The Brightgauge agent requres the following info, which we provided:

HostName: xxxx.public.xxxxx.database.windows.net
Port: 3342
Database Name: [dbname]
Db UserName: [user]
Db Password: [pwd]

This is what we know:

From the VM, test-netconnection executes successfully to the hostname/port.
All of our other applications can connect to the Azure Sql Managed Instance just fine, including SSMS that is installed on the VM.
The Brightgauge agent can successfully connect to our other Azure Sql Databases, just not Azure Sql Managed Instance
On the Azure Sql Managed Instance, we have enabled all traffic on all ports, and enabled public access
The connection failed even when we have TLS 1.0 as the minimum version

From the agent logs, the only additional detailed info we get is:
[TEST_NEW_CONNECTION] TRACE_ID: "10.xx.xx.xxx_[random guid]",
failed to open connection with database, TLS Handshake failed:
cannot read handshake packet: EOF

Where the 10.xx.x.x is an IP defined in the subnet of the managed instance's network security group.
Is there a configuration we are missing that is currently blocking the connection?
